# `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when run it in cmd

Tags: java

I'm in `/Users/gqqnbig/SourceCode/Java/PlayerStatisticReader/bin`.

```
Macintosh:bin gqqnbig$ ls
BasketballRules.class           PlayerGameStatistic.class
BuildMode.class             PlayerQuarterStatistic.class
EspnGameRecord.class            PlayerStatistic.class
GamePartiesData.class           Program.class
GameParty.class             mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar
```

I run my program, but `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown.

```
Macintosh:bin gqqnbig$ java  Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at Program.main(Program.java:33)
```

This is where the exception was thrown.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/NBA", "root", "");
```

My code is not in any package.

My code runs in Eclipse. How can I make it run in cmd?

Comment: `java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar  Program`

Comment: Check the links on the right: **Related** - most of the answers to this question will be there.

Comment: @helderdarocha then it says "Could not find or load main class Program"

Comment: `java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar Program` (the '`.:`') part is important at the beginning of your cp

Comment: @morgano has the answer for you

Comment: @femtoRgon Not duplicate. I use Mac, he uses Windows; and my code runs in Eclipse but fails in cmd.

Comment: also, if it runs in eclipse, you can look at the command line that eclipse generated to run your code.  eclipse isn't magic, it is simply invoking the jvm with specific command line settings.

Comment: Where do I look at the command line?